# How Comparisons Indicate Opinion

Tags: connotations

In the following two sentences, is there a different opinion being expressed about the father's books and if yes, why?

1. The son's books are worse than the father's.
2. The son's books are not as good as the father's.

Comment: Books are good or bad based on opinion, yes. Books have more or fewer pages based on fact.

Comment: No, both sentences mean the same, but the first suggests that the speaker has a poor opinion of the father's books, the second is either putting it more politely or may mean that the speaker admires the father's books.

Comment: Comparisons can state facts and do not necessarily reveal attitude at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming the speaker has a reasonable grasp of the situation]

Yes, the two statements are not equivalent.

We're rarely in logic school, using language in a black and white fashion.

Pragmatically, 'worse' at least connotes that both are bad. 'Not as good' connotes that the father's are at least good (otherwise an articulate speaker would rephrase), but leaves the son's at arguably 30 - 80% of the way up the excellence scale. Below 30%, one would probably be more scathing; over 80%, one would hardly criticise, or at least use a 'not quite'.

Comment: I'm not sure that "worse" suggests that both are bad. However, "even worse" would.

Comment: In 'His silence was worse than his anger', 'worse' obviously implies that his anger was bad enough. 'Worse' carries at least a connotation that, 'if 'A is worse than B', neither is especially good.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a good example, since anger is negative to begin with. I don't feel that implication in the OP's sentence A, although I can see how one might.

Comment: I think few would interpret *He played guitar worse than Hendrix* as a compliment to Jimi.

Comment: ... and playing the guitar is rarely seen as an inherent negative. // A lady has just discovered an autograph of Hendrix's from before he was famous in some scrapbooks she almost binned without perusing, jimm.